# Android Kotlin SonarQube shows 0% code coverage with kover

Tags: android, kotlin, sonarqube, jacoco, kover

Trying to get kotlin code coverage using kover in my android kotlin project, the coverage report says code coverage is **59%** however on sonarQube dashboard it reflects **0%**

Used below command to generate report:

```
*`./gradlew koverReport sonarqube `*
```

Below arw the projects gradle files

Module  gradle

```
apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
    apply plugin: 'kover'
    
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 32
        buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
    
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 32
           
        }
    
    

buildTypes {
release {}
debug {testCoverageEnabled true}
    
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        }
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '11'
        }
    
        flavorDimensions "flavor_Dimensions"
    
        productFlavors {
            dev {
      }
            stage {
                
            }
    
      }
       
    }
```

SonarQube  properties

```
sonarqube {
        properties {
            property "sonar.projectName", "project_name"
            property "sonar.projectKey", "project_key"
            property "sonar.host.url", "https:///hostUrl"
            property "sonar.language", "kotlin"
            property "sonar.sources", "src/main/"
            property "sonar.tests", "src/test/"
            property "sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "kover"
            property "sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPat", "build/reports/kover/xml/report.xml"
            property "sonar.test.inclusions", "**/*Test*/**"
            property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
          
            property "sonar.exclusions", '**/*Test*/**,' +
                    '*.json,' +
                    '**/*test*/**,' +
                    '**/.gradle/**,' +
                    '**/R.class,' +
                    '**/R$*.class'
        }
    }
```

task used to get coverage report from Kover

```
koverMerged {
    enable()  // create Kover merged reports
    filters {
      
    }

    xmlReport {
        onCheck.set(true)
    }

    htmlReport {
        onCheck.set(true)
    }

    verify {
        onCheck.set(true)
    }
}
    

Project gradle  
   

buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.4.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:3.3"
     
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kover:0.6.0-Beta"
     
    }
}
```

Comment: did you manage to find the solution to this?

Comment: Probably the spelling error? `sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPat` which should be `sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths`